# Providing an implementation when both trait and type are not in this crate

Tags: traits, rust

I want to provide an implementation of a trait `ToHex` (not defined by me, from `serialize`) for a primitive type `u8`:

```rust
impl ToHex for u8 {
    fn to_hex(&self) -> String {
        self.to_str_radix(16)
    }
}
```

The problem is I get this compiler error:

```
error: cannot provide an extension implementation where both trait and type are not defined in this crate
```

I understand the reason of this error and its logic, this is because both the trait and the primitive type are external to my code. But how can I handle this situation and provide an `ToHex` implementation for `u8`? And more generally how do you handle this kind of issue, it seems to me that this problem must be common and it should be possible and easy to extend types like this?

Answer (score 16):

You should use a newtype struct to do this:

```rust
pub struct U8(pub u8)

impl ToHex for U8 {
    fn to_hex(&self) -> String {
        let U8(x) = *self;
        x.to_str_radix(16)
    }
}
```

This does mean, however, that you should wrap `u8` into `U8` where you need to perform this conversion:

```rust
let x: u8 = 127u8

// println!("{}", x.to_hex());   // does not compile
println!("{}", U8(x).to_hex());
```

This is absolutely free in terms of performance.

Comment: It is a nice hack you propose. But in my case I worry it would be a little bit too cumbersome to wrap all the primitive types I use like that.

Comment: @user3762625, it is not a hack, it is in fact the only possible method. You can't add trait implementations of traits you don't own to types you don't own, and there is no workaround but newtypes.

Comment: @user3762625: Well, in the case presented, it would be simpler to have a `to_hex` free-function for `u8` directly (which you can define); you only really need to wrap when you need to pass a `u8` where `ToHex` is expected.

Answer (score 6):

I realize this is almost a year old, but the answer was never accepted and I think I've found an alternate solution, that I thought would be good to document here.

In order to extend the functionality of the **u8** through traits, instead of trying to extend **ToHex**, why not create a new trait?

```
trait MyToHex {
    fn to_hex(&self) -> String;
}

impl MyToHex for u8 {
    fn to_hex(&self) -> String {
        format!("{:x}", *self)
    }
}
```

then used like so

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", (16).to_hex());
}
```

This has the advantage that you don't have to wrap every **u8** variable with a new and superfluous data type.

The disadvantage is that you still can't use a **u8** in a external function (i.e std library, or one you have no control over) that requires the **ToHex** trait (Vladimir Matveev's solution works in this case), but from OP it sounds like all you want to do is extend **u8** only inside your code.